# Can't see contextMenu on UIComponent, but on its subviews in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a UIComponent (tried it also with Canvas) and some icons in it (sub views). On the UIComponent I defined some extra ContextMenuItems.
Now when I'm testing it, the context menu appears only on the subviews (icons) with a right-click.

I've checked the documentation but found nothing about required properties for using context menus.

Do you have any ideas why it's only on subviews?

Comment: Let me understand what you're trying to accomplish.  Are you trying to get a context menu to popup up with a specific entries when the person clicks the icons, canvas, label or all of them?  Could you post some code on how you're trying to accomplish this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What the problem was is the *mouseEnabled="{false}"* property in one of the parent-parent containers. I removed it and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening because your UIComponent's (or Canvas') graphics are clean/empty. If the component doesn't have any "content" it will act as transparent, which means the click event will not be caught.

If you are using a Canvas there's a simple way to check this out, try to add some background color and it should work:

```
<mx:Canvas backgroundColor="#FFFFFF" backgroundAlpha="0.001"/>
```

Comment: I have several other elements on it, like a label, an extra canvas (full rect - acts as a background) and the icons. I tried the background color also, but nothing did change.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code? Are you using any `Video` components?

Comment: Canvas does have a background.  This is not the issue.

Comment: @J_A_X Try to run your code without the "backgroundColor" property on the canvas and you will notice that your custom ContextMenuItems won't appear (they only appear in the canvas' children, in this case, the Button).

Comment: Oh, now I get it, sorry.  However, you don't need to specify the backgroundAlpha as 0.001.  Just 0 will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               creationComplete="onCreationComplete()">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function onCreationComplete():void
            {
                var menu:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
                menu.customItems.push(new ContextMenuItem('weee'));
                menu.customItems.push(new ContextMenuItem('weee2'));
                menu.hideBuiltInItems();
                canvas.contextMenu = menu;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:Canvas id="canvas" backgroundColor="#000000" height="50%" width="50%" >
        <s:Button label="blarg" />
    </mx:Canvas>
</s:Application>
```

Notice how I'm creating a menu, then adding items, which then replaces the contextMenu property.  This should work on any object that extends InteractiveObject.

Comment: When using a container, it needs to have a background of some sort to be able to listen to mouse events.  If you only want the menu in that canvas, then add a background color and make the backgroundAlpha equal 0.

Comment: I think I have the problem at a different area. All your examples are working for me too (if I'm creating it from scratch). But not in the current project I have to problem in.
I tried to remove effects, change containers (Canvas to Container to UIContainer), change layers, action handlers, events ... but so far no success. So technically you're completely right. And my question is: what can steal the context menu form a ui item?

Comment: Something important to remember about context menus: "In Flex or Flash Builder, only top-level components in the application can have context menus. For example, if a DataGrid control is a child of a TabNavigator or VBox container, the DataGrid control cannot have its own context menu."  you're probably trying to add it to a child component.  I would recommend you think of another way to create the user experience.  Personally, I never use right click in case we need to adapt for a touch screen :)

Comment: I've read that in the documentation and the interesting thing that it worked before. (Although it's indeed child of some top-level component.) I have a graph editing app and every node has functions you can reach in the context menu. I'm chasing it still but at the end maybe I move the functions from the context menu.

Comment: I tried if that child-of-a-toplevel-component is really valid:
http://pastebin.com/5n2QDs7W
For me it even works: contextMenu on a DataGrid in a VBox. Weird.

Comment: yeah, I've seen some weird behavior around this as well.  Not too sure why.